# Sony Smartwatch Emulator: Getting started

Tags: emulation, sony-smartwatch

I downloaded Sony's most recent SDK which includes an unusual Emulator that is an APK that runs on an Android phone (I guess that is what you do with it).

Anyway I see no documentation about how to use this to `test/deploy` apps.

Am I supposed to have 2 phones and one runs the emulator and the other runs the "host application" or do I run the host application on the same phone or what?

Nothing that I can find in docs explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured this out (sort of). You run the emulator on your phone, then run the Smart Extension app on your phone as well (so no bluetooth connectivity like when you have a real smartwatch).

Phone also needs to have the SmartConnect (previously LiveWare) app and the SmartWatch app installed (I think). So that's three apps (emulator, SmartConnect, SmartWatch app).

Anyway, my actual smartwatch arrived in the mail shortly after I posted the original question, so I probably won't be using emulator much anymore.